# Browser Timing out waiting for Soap Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap-client

I'm working on an application which gets some data from a web service using a PHP soap client. The web service accesses the clients SQL server, which has very slow performance (some requests will take several minutes to run).

Everything works fine for the smaller requests, but if the browser is waiting for 2 minutes, it prompts me to download a blank file.

I've increased the php max_execution_time, memory_limit and default_socket_timeout, but the browser will always seem to stop waiting at exactly 2 minutes.

Any ideas on how to get the brower to hang around indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your architecture from pull to push. Then the user can carrying on using your web application & be notified when the data is ready.

Or as a simple work around (not ideal) if you are able to modify the soap server you could have another web service that checks if the data is ready, then on the client you could call this every 30secs to keep checking if data is available rather than waiting.

Answer (score 0):

The web server was timing out - in my case, Apache. I initially thought it was something else as I increased the timeout value in httpd.conf, and it was still stopping after two minutes. However, I'm using Zend Server, which has an additional configuration file which was setting the timeout to 120 seconds - I increased this and the browser no longer stops after two minutes.